# How to mock mongodb for unit testing graphql resolver

Tags: node.js, mongodb, unit-testing, mongoose, graphql

I am learning graphql and want to do the unit testing for my resolver ( i.e. the query to get "answers").The problem is my resolver use mongoose to query data from mongodb behind the scene and I dont know how to mock these calls.

Could anyone help me with this ? Thank you.

The resolver for my query is sth like this:

```
const { Book, Author } = require('../models')    

module.exports = {
  answers: async ( parent, { searchText } ) => {        
    let authors = null;
    let books = null;
    try {
        authors = await Author.find({});            
        books = await Book.find({}); 
        return getAnswers(authors,books, searchText);
    }catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }        
    return null;
 }
}

function getAnswers(books,authors,text) {
    <!-- process data here -->
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for [proxyquire](https://www.npmjs.com/package/proxyquire). It lets you override the dependencies in a file you require. Your test file could look something like this

```
const proxyquire = require('proxyquire');
const mockBook = {...}

describe('Test #1', function() {
    const stubs = {
        '../models': {
            Book: {
                find: () => Promise.resolve(mockBook),
            },
            Author: // Same as book
        },
    };

    const myfile = proxyquire('./myfile', stubs);
    let answers;

    before(async function() {
        answers = await myfile.answers();
    });

    describe("should succeed", function() {
        expect(answers).to.be.equal(ExpectedAnswers);
    });
});
```

Now, that code has not been run and will definitely not succeed. This was to give you an idea of how to use proxyquire.

As for the `getAnswers()` part of the code, you will need to mock the dependencies of that function as well, like it is done for `Book` in the sample above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **graphql-tools** [here is a link to the blog](https://blog.apollographql.com/mocking-your-server-with-just-one-line-of-code-692feda6e9cd)

```
npm install graphql-tools
```

import your schema into your test file

```
import { mockServer } from 'graphql-tools';
import schema from './schema.js';

describe('mock server', () => {
  it('should mock the server call', async () => {
    const myMockServer = mockServer(schema, {
      String: () => 'Hello', // <--- expecting a `hello` to be returned
    });
    const response = await myMockServer.query(`{
      users {
        username,
      }
    }`);

    const expected =  { // This shape of the data returned
      data: {
        users: [
          {
            "username": "Hello"
          },
          {
            "username": "Hello"
          },
       ]
    }
  }
  expect(response).toMatchObject(expected);
});
});
```

Comment: graphql-tools allows you to create a mockServer. The question is asking about mocking calls to MongoDB *within* a server.